# Looking for bug tracking software

Tags: looking-for-a-script, bugs, ticket-system, issue-trackers

I'm looking for a bug/issue tracking system that can:

- Integrate with lots of other services. Basecamp, Beanstalk, etc.
- Integrate popular CMSs, such as WordPress, so the client can enter a ticket from the system that is familiar to them and not have one more login to worry about.
- Generate reports for my own purposes.
- Bonus if there's an iPhone app.
- Doesn't require additional development on my end (I have plenty of money and no time).

I've already looked into Lighthouse and ZenDesk -- both are solid offerings -- but don't see what I need out of the box. I'd have to build CMS plug-ins. And I've looked through WP plug-ins for bug tracking software, but nothing I've found integrates with these products.

Anyone know of something that meets these requirements without additional development, or am I stuck putting my business on hold to get this piece in place myself?

Comment: You can look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue-tracking_systems

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you have too much requirements for an existing product. The only fact that the system must integrate with popular CMS is an incredibly huge requirement. Also, it fights with your last requirement "it doesn't require additional development".

The only solution that exactly fits all your needs is a custom solution. If you want to use an existing solution, you need to adapt yourself and reduce the requirements.

[Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) (see also [Chiliproject](https://www.chiliproject.org/) fork) is a good solution. It's enterprise-ready, it's free, it comes with an iPhone application and it supports plugins so that you can easily develop additional integrations or modules. Also, it supports LDAP out-of-the-box, in this way you can integrate the login system with your company LDAP server, in case you have one.

I know about several other issue trackers, including [YouTrack](http://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/), [Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/), [Fogbugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/), but none of them is that flexible.

Comment: Dude -- Thanks for the link to Redmine. I had looked at it a long time ago but didn't realize it had become so popular and well-supported. You're right, I was a bit contradictory. I don't want to have to write integrations with all the APIs, so I think I'll go with something like lighthouse that integrates with most of my other services and then just hire someone to write the last leg, integration with a chosen CMS.